# POST not behaving correctly with mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form in a file `index.php` that posts to a second page like this:

```
    <form method="post" id="signupform" name="signupform" action="functions.php">
        <label for="user_id">Username:</label><span id="asterix">*</span> <br>
        <input name="user_id" type="text" id="user_id" required><br><br>
        <label for="new_password">Password:</label><span id="asterix">*</span> <br>
        <input name="new_password" type="password" id="new_password" required><br><br>
        <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password:</label><span id="asterix">*</span> <br>
        <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" type="password" required><br><br>
        <label for="new_email">Email:</label><span id="asterix">*</span> <br>
        <input name="new_email" id="new_email" type="email" required>
        <input hidden="hidden" name="action" value="signup">
        <br><br>
        <input id="createaccount" type="submit" value="Create account">
    </form>
```

The submit is done through jQuery `submitHandler` like this:

```
                submitHandler: function(signupform) {
                $(signupform).ajaxSubmit({

                    target:'#result',
                    success: function(){
                        $("#result").css("display","block");
                        $('#box').animate({'top':'-800px'},500,function(){
                            $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('#loginmain').hide();
                        });

                    }
                })
            }
```

The result is shown in a div in the same page as follows:

```
<div id="result" class="success_message" style="display: none"></div>
```

On the second page, `functions.php`, I have what needs to be displayed in the div.

Now the problem is that I created a third file called db.php to do database operations.

```
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "signup") {
    $user_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_id"]);
    $new_password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["new_password"]));
    $new_email    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["new_email"]);

    $create_account = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password ) VALUES ('" . $user_id . "','" . $new_password . "','" . $new_email . "')";
    if($create_account){echo "done";}else echo "failed";
    if(mysqli_query($str, $create_account)){
        echo "successful insert";
    }
 }
```

Although I have included db.php in the index.php, the queries do not get executed because in fact, it seems that the form does not `post`correctly because if I put an `echo "test"` after the `if` statement, it does not show, but if I replace the `action="functions.php"` by `action=""`, things work, but then the `submithandler` does not behave correctly.

Comment: Did you include db.php on your functions.php file?

Comment: if you could put it as an answer, i'd be glad to accept it!

Comment: Using MD5 for encoding passwords is a very, very **bad idea**. Is this a legacy application, or something new?

Comment: @tadman, Im quite a newbie in php.. I didnt know there are other encryption methods. I'll check them out. Thanks !

Comment: @Suvimo If you're just getting started, it's best to use a password specific encryption method like [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) as used in [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). Bcrypt is an adaptive algorithm that can be made artificially harder to guard against increased password cracking performance and is highly recommended. MD5 is instantly crackable and SHA1 and SHA2 are very easy to crack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include db.php in functions.php as well in order to have these functions work there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you specify `type=hidden` instead of `hidden=hidden` in your `input` declaration as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="signup">
```

instead of

```
<input hidden="hidden" name="action" value="signup">
```

Did you check the posted values in your php scripts before the `if` statement?